# asp.net mvc 5 + automapper 'Mapper' does not contain a definition for 'CreateMap'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Пытаюсь настроить в mvc проекте automapper.

Имею два класса:

- Person (доменная модель бд)
- PersonViewModel(модель представления)

Код контроллера:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IPersonRepository _repo;

        public HomeController(IPersonRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // сопоставление классов
            var model = Mapper.Map<List<Person>, List<PersonViewModel>>(_repo.Get());
            return View(model);
        }
```

AutoMapperа вынес в отдельный класс. В нем и выходит ошибка

```
public static void RegisterMappings()
{
   Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>(); //'Mapper' does not contain a definition for 'CreateMap'
}
```

в мануалах нашел правильную настройку, но как ее грамотно настроить и так чтоб не создавать mapper в каждом методе контроллера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий для версий automapper 4 <. В версии 5 метод метод CreateMap удален из класса Mapper.
Подробнее [тут](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1031)

### **UPDATE**

В папке App_Start создадим 2 класса

```
public class MapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(_ =>
        {
            _.AddProfile(new MapperProfile());
        });
    }
}

public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        //создаем маппинг к примеру           
        CreateMap<PersonDto, PersonViewModel>()
        .ReverseMap(); //если нужно в обе стороны
    }
}
```

в файле Global.asax создаем свойство MapperConfiguration и 
регистрируем его в методе Application_Start()

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    internal static MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration { get; private set; }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        MapperConfiguration = MapperConfig.GetConfiguration(); // <---
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //остальное скрыто
    }
}
```

Создаем базовый контроллер в нем будет свойство типа Mapper

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private IMapper _mapper = null;
    protected IMapper Mapper
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mapper == null) _mapper = MvcApplication.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
            return _mapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь в методе контроллера используем свойство Mapper базового контроллера

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _repo;

    public HomeController IPersonRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        <IList>PersonDto dto = _repo.Get();
        <IList>PersonViewModel model = Mapper.Map<IList<Person>, IList<PersonViewModel>>(dto);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: подскажите как настроить на 5ой версии